# Loop without resetting vars

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

I've been working on this code all morning and still I haven't found a way to do what I want to, basically this here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class bestellen : MonoBehaviour {

    string stringtoedit = " ";
    int voercounter = 0;

    void OnGUI(){

    var saveddoc = File.OpenText("C:/KleindierparkAdministratie/voer/voer.txt");
    var line = saveddoc.ReadLine();

    GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), line);
    stringtoedit = GUI.TextField(new Rect(100, 10, 200, 20), stringtoedit, 25);
    var voerdoc = File.OpenText("C:/KleindierparkAdministratie/voer/" + line + ".txt");
    var line2 = voerdoc.ReadLine();
    int counter = 1;
    while(line2 != null){
        if(counter == 5){
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350, 10, 100, 20), line2);
        }

        counter++;
        line2 = voerdoc.ReadLine();
    }

    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (25, 50, 250, 30), "Next")) {

        line = saveddoc.ReadLine();
        Debug.Log (line);

    }   

}
```

}

What I am trying to do is have it read out the next line of a text document every time when I click the button, however due to the fact that it recalls

```
var saveddoc = File.OpenText("C:/KleindierparkAdministratie/voer/voer.txt");
var line = saveddoc.ReadLine();
```

every single time it doesn't work and I have not a single clue on how I would go about fixing this, so now my question is do any of you guys know how to fix a thing like this?

Comment: u are calling onGUI function on button click?

Comment: Just don't reopen the file. Either store the TextReader returned to a field the first time you open it, or read all lines at once with ReadAllLines, store the string array to a field and iterate over the field

Comment: @Muneem No I do not run OnGUI on a button click. I just let OnGUI run as it is supposed to, however if you look at my code you can see that I am trying to change certain values when I press the button, but due to OnGUI being a loop it resets those values at the beggining of it.

Comment: @Panagiotis I don't fully understand what you mean by storing the whole TextReader, but I'll google a bit and see if that is a suitable way of fixing this. I hope it works, thanks already

EDIT: It worked, thanks loads for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this in the OnGUI event itself is definitely not the best thing to do since it can **be called several times per frame**!!

The [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) is pretty clear on that:

> OnGUI is called for rendering and handling GUI events. **This means that your OnGUI implementation might be called several times per frame** (one call per event). For more information on GUI events see the Event reference. If the MonoBehaviour's enabled property is set to false, OnGUI() will not be called.

That means that your code in it's current state is opening that file *potentially* several times per frame that your game is running.

It would be better to read in the contents of the entire file in either the Start or Awake event and storing that as a global variable of the class. You will also want to track the number of lines you have read, so each time the button is pressed you can just increment the lines read and at that point read the next line from the file.

A quick example of this would be...

```
private string[] _allLines;
private int _linesRead;
void Start() { 
    _linesRead = 0;
    var savedDoc = File.OpenText("C:/KleindierparkAdministratie/voer/voer.txt");
    _allLines = savedDoc.ReadAllLines();
}
void OnGUI() {
    if (/* Button pressed*/) {
    // read next line and do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have decided to do it in that way. The best option could be to read documents outside OnGUI because OnGUI is called several times for frame.

Nevertheless, find here a solution using your more or less you idea (check comments in the code):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class bestellen : MonoBehaviour {

    string stringtoedit = " ";
    int voercounter = 0;
    string line = "";
    string line2 = "";
    var saveddoc;

    void Start()
    {
        saveddoc = File.OpenText("C:/KleindierparkAdministratie/voer/voer.txt");
    }

    void OnGUI(){

        GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), line);
        stringtoedit = GUI.TextField(new Rect(100, 10, 200, 20), stringtoedit, 25);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(350, 10, 100, 20), line2);

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (25, 50, 250, 30), "Next")) {

            line = saveddoc.ReadLine();
            Debug.Log (line);
            var voerdoc = File.OpenText("C:/KleindierparkAdministratie/voer/" + line + ".txt");
            var lineTemp = voerdoc.ReadLine();
            int counter = 1;
            // in this loop you are reading the whole document just to keep the 5th line.
            // Consider refactor the loop just to read the desired line
            while(lineTemp != null){
                if(counter == 5){
                    line2 = lineTemp;
                }

                counter++;
                lineTemp = voerdoc.ReadLine();
            }
            // Close here voerdoc!!!!

        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. My code is kinda clumsy right now and I need to refactor a lot of it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of Panagiotis I managed to fix it. For anyone interested for future reference here is the new code:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class bestellen : MonoBehaviour {

```
string stringtoedit = " ";
int voercounter = 0;

TextReader saveddoc;
string line;

void Start(){

    saveddoc = File.OpenText("C:/KleindierparkAdministratie/voer/voer.txt");
    line = saveddoc.ReadLine();

}

void OnGUI(){

    GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), line);
    stringtoedit = GUI.TextField(new Rect(100, 10, 200, 20), stringtoedit, 25);
    var voerdoc = File.OpenText("C:/KleindierparkAdministratie/voer/" + line + ".txt");
    var line2 = voerdoc.ReadLine();
    int counter = 1;
    while(line2 != null){
        if(counter == 5){
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350, 10, 100, 20), line2);
        }

        counter++;
        line2 = voerdoc.ReadLine();
    }

    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (25, 50, 250, 30), "Next")) {

        line = saveddoc.ReadLine();
        Debug.Log (line);

    }   

}
```

}

Thanks for all the help guys :)